# WMS service with Swift / iOS

Tags: swift, mapkit, wms

Knows somebody a book or an example/tutorial to implement an WMS service in Swift? The layer need zoomable with the map.

I'm having a WMS service in Android and I read the tutorial:
[MapKit Tutorial: Overlay Views](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial)

but I'm a beginner in Swift and I don't know how to integrate it.
Thanks a lot.

Here the sample code:

```
    let url = "https://geoserver/wms?LAYERS=Karte&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG:900913&BBOX=464201.39551181,5902292.6044465,1836379.4732096,7388629.6749115&width=256&height=256&format=image/png8&transparent=true"

    var overlay = MyTileOverlay(URLTemplate:url)
    self.mapView.addOverlay(overlay)



class MyTileOverlay : MKTileOverlay {
var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

 func URLForTilePath(path: MKTileOverlayPath,
    result: ((NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {

        super.loadTileAtPath(path, result) } }
```

The problem are the dynamic BBOX in the url, with the correct x, y and zoom.

The result:
[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur0apyjfwiz69vs/Unbenannt.png?dl=0)

Comment: Have u heard Mapkit?

Comment: Yes, the Mapkit is integrate in the project. My problem is, the picture that deliver from the WMS Server to implement as layer on the map.

Comment: I have same question with you, Could you get some sulotion?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a code for GoogleMaps and MapKit, updated for Swift 2.0. I prefer GoogleMaps. You can find it under: https://github.com/revilosun/WMS_GoogleMap_Swift. For MapKit, I want upload in the next time.

Comment: Now for MapKit: https://github.com/revilosun/WmsMapKit_Swift